# Access to variables in scope from a function defined externally

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to print the value of temp (a closure variable) from a function defined outside the closure but referenced within the closure without passing temp as a variable to funcA?

```
var funcA, funcB;

funcA = function () {
   console.log(temp);
}

funcB = function () {var temp, funcC;
  temp = 1;
  funcC = funcA;
  funcC();
}
funcB();  // temp is undefined.
```

This works, but only because funcA is defined within funcB:

```
funcB = function () {var temp, funcA, funcC;
  temp = 1;
  funcA = function () {
       console.log(temp);
  }
  funcC = funcA;
  funcC();
}
funcB(); // 1
```

I'm trying to find a way to pull some function definitions out of outer functions to streamline code that's getting a little complex.  Can I define funcA outside of funcB but still reference the temp variable without having to pass parameters?

I read that javascript does not have dynamic run time scoping, that it's only lexical scoping, but with referencing a function (funcA via funcC) within funcB, is there a way to meet the lexical scope requirement and provide access to the scoped variables for funcB?

Comment: Functions can only access variables defined in their scope (function scope) and the variables defined in the global scope. `funcA` will not be able to access `temp` in `funcB` because it is not a closure. If you want to have access to `temp` from whatever function, define it on the global scope.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Questions like this need a real world example to advise on a good solution to your **actual** problem.

Comment: @Akinkunle  You just gave me an idea for a solution.  I'll post it.  I can wrap the whole thing in a function and use that function's scope (like a global scope, but restricted to my application).

Comment: @ChrisG. Yes, that is how modules are written. You wrap up your whole code in a big function scope so that the global scope will not be polluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Akinkunle Allen's comment, I came up with this which seems to solve my problem.

```
function funcB () {
  var funcA, funcB, temp;

  funcA = function () {
     console.log(temp);
  }

  funcB = function () {var funcC;
    temp = 1;
    funcC = funcA;
    funcC(); 
  }
  return funcB();
}

funcB(); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and No.

The keyword `var` for declaring variables behaves different depending upon what the current scope is. When `var` is executed on the global scope it is optional. The variable becomes a property of the global object. When executing in the browser this global object is `window`.

So the following in global space has the same result.

```
var temp = 1;
window.temp = 1;
this.temp = 1;
```

All the above is just `window.temp` because of the global context.

When you use `var` inside a function then the variable is *attached* to the function. All functions in Javascript are objects so local `var` variables will live as long as the parent function is still being used somewhere.

Javascript will walk the hierarchy of executing scopes to find a variable identifier. So any inner functions can access their outer function variables (as in your example).

What you can do is play around with the `this` reference in functions.

The identifier `this` in Javascript is dynamic (meaning that you can change it). I can pass a variable to an unknown function that was declared outside the calling function. Since the `this.temp` is used to reference the variable the function `funcA` is able to display the value.

```
funcB = function(otherFunc)
{
    this.temp = 1;
    otherFunc();
}

funcA = function()
{
    alert(this.temp);
}

funcB(funcA);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/dfLvj/

See the above jsfiddle example.

What you can do with this is change the meaning of `this` on the fly. Here is a better example.

```
funcB = function(otherFunc)
{
    var temp = {
        message: "Hello World!"
    };
    var foo = otherFunc.bind(temp);
    foo();
}

funcA = function()
{
    alert(this.message);
}

funcB(funcA);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/K5Pw6/

Dynamically changing `this` can have a lot of benefits by allowing a function to accept closure references that will be executed with a custom `this` reference.

An example might be a click event handler where `this` is the DOM element that triggered the event.

Comment: I see what you're doing, but I'm trying to avoid passing parameters (since I use that for something else).  I just want to move my function definitions but still retain the ability for those functions to access variables that are used in the original function.  Example temp was used in funcB and referenced in FuncA.  I want to keep that, but I want to move the definition of funcA out of funcB to keep funcB simpler (less code inside it).

Comment: @ChrisG. that sounds more like the need for objects. Have you learn how to use constructor functions and prototyping in Javascript?